# How to create PDF from webview in android?

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I am displaying `webpage` in `webview`. Now **how to create PDF from webview** ?

For Example : webview loads URL is `"www.google.co.in"`. Now how to save this webpage as image and create pdf ??

any help would be appreciated

Comment: searching for online API or local API.?

Comment: @SilentKiller anyone no matters.

Comment: try to implement of @Aamirkhan code..it will solve ur problem.

Comment: @Prince try with following answer else [here](http://pdfcrowd.com/html-to-pdf-api/) is online api

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try like this

WebView have inbuilt method called `setPictureListener` Use that method as below

```
webView1.setPictureListener(new PictureListener() {

            public void onNewPicture(WebView view, Picture picture) {
                if (picture != null) {
                    try {
                        bmp = pictureDrawable2Bitmap(new PictureDrawable(
                                picture));

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

For obtaining bitmap i have used `pictureDrawable2Bitmap` and here is that one

```
private static Bitmap pictureDrawable2Bitmap(PictureDrawable pictureDrawable) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.drawPicture(pictureDrawable.getPicture());
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Now Your Bitmap is ready,Now set webview client as below

```
webView1.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
```

And here is `myWebClient`

```
public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            Log.i("OnPageLoadFinished", url);
            img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
```

As shown on page load finished i have set image bitmap which is snap of current loaded url on your webview

Now Bitmap is ready pass that bitmap to Pdf using IText Library

Here is an example of writing pdf with image on iText Use Below function for that

```
public void SimplePDFTable() throws Exception {

    File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/AamirPDF");
    if (!direct.exists()) {
        if (direct.mkdir()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Folder Is created in sd card", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
    String test = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/AamirPDF";
    Document document = new Document();

    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(test
            + "/mypdf.pdf"));

    document.open();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    Image image = Image.getInstance(byteArray);


    image.scaleToFit(PageSize.A4.getHeight(), PageSize.A4.getWidth());
    document.add(image);

    document.close();

}
```

Good Luck

Comment: @Prince WC,My Pleasure :)

Comment: When will this "OnPictureListener" get called? I mean on what actions?

Comment: @VickyS It will called Every time automatically when new page is loaded on WebView, I mean we don't need to trigger this event, it will be called Automatically whenever any new page is loaded on WebView

Comment: @Prince how can I save the webview as pdf directly without converting it to image initially? is there any shortcut way to do that?

Comment: @CrazyLearner my be it's possible converting webview's html to pdf

Comment: But iText is paid library not free one.

Comment: @Aamirkhan Can we add-footer on every page of PDF? (Footer must be from PDF not from web view). Will appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 4):

As of API 19 (KitKat), Android now lets you [print a webview](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs.html) directly.  Moreover, the same **PrintManager** API can be used to generate a PDF from a **WebView** without any external libraries.

As the example code shows, just get the **PrintManager**, create a **PrintDocumentAdapter** from the **WebView** in question, then create a new **PrintJob** and your user should see the option to save it to a file as PDF or print to a cloud printer.  On newer Androids than 4.4 they'll also get a visual preview of what will be printed/PDF'd.

Comment: any examples or link!?

Comment: And who exactly asked for printing?!

Comment: printing comes "for free" on the output to pdf screen.  Just change the "save-to-pdf" menu item to a cloud printer.

Answer (score 0):

### if can not want return path

```
private fun createWebPrintJob(webView: WebView) {
    val printManager = this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE) as PrintManager
    val printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter()
    val jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Print Test"
    printManager.print(
        jobName, printAdapter,
        PrintAttributes.Builder().build()
    )
}
```

### if can want return path of PDF


**try this**

lib :

```
implementation 'com.github.pramodkr123:ConvertWebViewToPdfDemo:1.0.4'
```

Kotlin CODE:

```
    private fun sentEmailAndSavePDF() {
    val directory =
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/MDP-PDF/")
    val min = 1000
    val max = 9999
    val random = Random().nextInt(max - min + 1) + min
    val fileName = "MDP_$random.pdf"

    PdfView.createWebPrintJob(
        this@WebViewActivity,
        binding.webview,
        directory,
        fileName,
        object : PdfView.Callback {
            override fun success(p0: String?) {

                Log.e(TAG, "success: ")
                   //p0  is your pdf PATH 
            }

            override fun failure() {

            }

        })
}
```