# Android: inflating a layout and writting it to PDF produces a blank PDF

Tags: android, android-layout, pdf, android-print-framework

when the user selects a share button within an activity, I would like to inflate a layout, populate it, and then write that layout to a pdf using the new printing API.

In my fragment I have

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
  public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.menu_item_share_context:
        LayoutInflator inflator = getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View container = inflator.inflate(R.layout.person_share, null, false);
        TextView name = (TextView)topContainer.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
        name.setText("Test Name");
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(612, 792, 1).create()
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo)
        container.draw(page.getCanvas());
        document.finishPage(page)

        // write pdf
        ...
```

This unfortunately outputs a blank pdf document. However, when I use a view that already exists on the screen (inflated in onCreateView(..)), it shows up in the pdf as expected.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Your layout has not gone through the layout and measure passes yet, and so my guess is that your `container` has a width and height of 0.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks. Any idea of how to make it go through the layout and measure passes? Or can I set an explicit width and height?

Answer (score 17):

If my theory is correct -- that your inflated layout still has a width and height of zero -- you can call `measure()` and `layout()` to manually size and position things:

```
root.measure(800, 480);
root.layout(0, 0, 800, 480);
```

Given a `View` named `root`, this will have it (and its children, if any) fill an 800-pixel wide by 480-pixel high space (e.g., a WVGA device, landscape, full-screen). In your case, you should be able to call `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` on the `Canvas` to determine the sizes to use for `measure()` and `layout()`.

FWIW, personally, I'd generate HTML and use that for the basis of printing, rather than a layout file. That's one of the techniques I demonstrate in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Printing/PrintManager).

Comment: Calling 'measure' and 'layout' worked. Thanks Comms.

Comment: Per your comment about generating HTML and using that to print, is it possible to create a PDF file from a webview and just save it without printing it? I couldn't figure out how to do that from your sample project.

Comment: @James: "is it possible to create a PDF file from a webview and just save it without printing it?" -- I don't believe so. Sorry, I thought your objective was to print, not just generate the PDF.

Comment: Ok thanks anyway. Possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511639/how-to-create-pdf-from-webview-in-android

Comment: I don't know why no one has approved this answer or given it more up-votes. I was having the same exact problem and this fixed it for me.