# webview into pdf using PdfDocument

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I want to convert webview into PDF document and save the document in external storage. The pdf should be similar to the one which we can generate we we print the webview and chose save as pdf instead of printing.

Code for Webview:

```
    WebView ww = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.ww);
    ww.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 Chrome/53.0.2785.116");
    ww.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("en-US,en;q=0.8");
    WebSettings webSettings = ww.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ww.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    ww.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    ww.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    ww.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    ww.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    ww.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

Comment: does this answer your question? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511639/how-to-create-pdf-from-webview-in-android

Comment: I want Open Source method... It uses library which is paid for commercial use @MatthewShearer

Comment: ah, you may be a bit stuck.  I'll have a look a bit longer

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the webview into a bitmap and then into a PDF document. The advantage of not converting directly to PDF is that you can scale the image to fit the PDF in any way you want.

This code converts a webview into a pdf page and then shares it, asking the user to select his printer app:

```
public static void sharePdfFile(WebView webView, Context context)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = webviewToBitmap( webView );
    PrintedPdfDocument pdf =  bitmapToPdf( bitmap, context );
    File file = pdfToFile( pdf, context );
    shareFile( file,"application/pdf", context );
}

private static void shareFile(File file, String contentType, Context context)
{
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        context,
        context.getPackageName() + ".fileprovider",
        file);
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType(contentType);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    Toast.makeText(
        context,
        "Choose your printer app",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
    ).show();
    context.startActivity( shareIntent );
}

private static File pdfToFile(PrintedPdfDocument printedPdfDocument, Context context)
{
    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "share.pdf");
    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        printedPdfDocument.writeTo(outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    printedPdfDocument.close();
    return file;
}


private static PrintedPdfDocument bitmapToPdf(Bitmap bitmap, Context context)
{
    PrintAttributes printAttributes = new PrintAttributes.Builder()
        .setColorMode(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_COLOR)
        .setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4)
        .setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS)
        .setResolution(new PrintAttributes.Resolution("1", "label", 300, 300))
        .build();
    PrintedPdfDocument printedPdfDocument = new PrintedPdfDocument(context, printAttributes);
    PdfDocument.Page pdfDocumentPage = printedPdfDocument.startPage(1);
    Canvas pdfCanvas = pdfDocumentPage.getCanvas();
    bitmap = scaleBitmapToHeight(bitmap, pdfCanvas.getHeight());
    pdfCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f, 0f, null);
    printedPdfDocument.finishPage(pdfDocumentPage);
    return printedPdfDocument;
}

private static Bitmap webviewToBitmap(WebView webView) {
    webView.measure(
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            0,
            View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED
        ),
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            0,
            View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED
        )
    );
    int webViewWidth = webView.getMeasuredWidth();
    int webViewHeight = webView.getMeasuredHeight();
    webView.layout(0,0, webViewWidth, webViewHeight );
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webViewWidth, webViewHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, bitmap.getHeight(), new Paint());
    webView.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}

private static Bitmap scaleBitmapToHeight(Bitmap bitmap, int maxHeight) {
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    if(height > maxHeight) {
        int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        float scalePercentage = ((float)maxHeight) / height;
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int) (width * scalePercentage), maxHeight, false);
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```