# Saving WebView Content to PDF

Tags: java, android

I want to save WebView Content to a PDF. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511639/how-to-create-pdf-from-webview-in-android#) link but i confused how to use it, I also want to add the File save dialog when user want to save it.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? if yes, please provide us what get you stuck. if no, please try something first.

Comment: From where to start? I dont know how to use the function