# Printing a WebView HTML content directly to a PDF file

Tags: android, pdf, webview

Using Android 19 print APIs, I'm trying to **render the content of a WebView directly into a PDF file on device storage**. I know I can send a `PrintJob` to `PrintManager` and let the user choose *"Save as PDF"* there, but I do not want that. I want to save the PDF immediately, from my app.

I tried using `WebView.draw(PdfDocument.Page.getCanvas())`, but the resulting PDF is raster, not vector  [Here's the result](https://www.lorenzostanco.com/stack/android-html2pdf-test-draw.pdf) (text not selectable, also try zooming) for the code below:

```
final String htmlDocument = "<html><body><h1>Test Content</h1><p>Testing, testing, testing...</p></body></html>";
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlDocument, "text/HTML", "UTF-8", null);

// ...The following is on web view client's onPageFinished()

final PrintAttributes attrs = new PrintAttributes.Builder()
    .setColorMode(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_COLOR)
    .setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4)
    .setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS)
    .setResolution(new PrintAttributes.Resolution("1", "label", 300, 300))
    .build();

final PrintedPdfDocument document = new PrintedPdfDocument(this, attrs);
final PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(1);

webView.draw(page.getCanvas());
// Also tried: webView.capturePicture().draw(page.getCanvas());
document.finishPage(page);

final FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.pdf"));
document.writeTo(outputStream);
outputStream.close();

document.close();
```

Given that sending a `PrintJob` to `PrintManager` produces a nice vector PDF with selectable text, I tried to use those APIs directly after reading how printing job works:

```
final PrintDocumentAdapter webViewPrintAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter();

outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test2.pdf");
final ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(outputFile, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_CREATE | ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE);

webViewPrintAdapter.onStart();
webViewPrintAdapter.onLayout(attrs, attrs, new CancellationSignal(), null, new Bundle());
webViewPrintAdapter.onWrite(new PageRange[]{ PageRange.ALL_PAGES }, fileDescriptor, new CancellationSignal(), null);
webViewPrintAdapter.onFinish();
```

The code above crashes because of NPEs with the two `null` callbacks. Problem is, I cannot implement a stub of those callbacks, because `LayoutResultCallback` and `WriteResultCallback` are package-protected.

So, my questions are:

1. Is it really possible to do what I'm trying to achieve here? I mean, making a PDF from a web view **without using system's printer UI**?
2. Why the `WebView.draw(PdfDocument.Page.getCanvas())` produces a raster PDF with non-selectable text?
3. Is it somehow possible to make use of the print adapter created by the web view itself, like I was trying to do in the second example?

Thank you.

Comment: Refer http://www.annalytics.co.uk/android/pdf/2017/04/06/Save-PDF-From-An-Android-WebView/ for more details, used your second approch in it.

Comment: I think this link can solve your problem Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511639/how-to-create-pdf-from-webview-in-android)!

Comment: @Akshay Thanks, it works! It's basically my second example, in which they managed to instantiate the callbacks with the trick suggested by CommonsWare in his answer

Comment: @lorenzo-s glad to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using Android 19 print APIs, I'm trying to render the content of a WebView directly into a PDF file on device storage.

The print APIs are for printing. They have never been for the creation of PDF files.

> Why the WebView.draw(PdfDocument.Page.getCanvas()) produces a raster PDF with non-selectable text?

`draw()` renders a UI to a `Canvas`, regardless of the source UI (`EditText`, `Button`, `ImageView`, `ViewPager`, `WebView`, some combination of widgets in a `ConstraintLayout`, etc.). If the `Canvas` is backed by a `Bitmap` — which is what they probably use here — you get a `Bitmap`.

> Is it somehow possible to make use of the print adapter created by the web view itself, like I was trying to do in the second example?

You can try putting your implementations of `LayoutResultCallback` and `WriteResultCallback` in your app in the `android.print` package, by adding that Java package as part of your project. As the saying goes, YMMV.